# Inline Assembler Syscall PTRACE(Operation not permitted)

Tags: c, assembly, system-calls, strace, ptrace

Hello I´ve got a Problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SYS_PTRACE 101
long my_ptrace(long pid)
{
long ret;
__asm__ volatile(
"mov $0x10, %%rdi\n"
"mov %0, %%rsi\n"
"xor %%rdx,%%rdx\n"
"xor %%r10, %%r10\n"
"mov $0x65, %%rax\n"
"syscall" : :"g"(pid)); 
__asm__ volatile("mov %%rax, %0" : "=r"(ret));
return ret;
}

int main()
{  
long a = getpid();
my_ptrace(a);
printf("Hello World\n %d", a);

return 0;
}
```

first I move 0x10 or 16 into rdi which is the number for PTRACE_ATTACH according to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/+/jb-dev/sysroot/usr/include/sys/ptrace.h

followed by moving the PID into rsi (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) the other values are not used by this call.

But if I compile and execute the Programm strace outputs

```
[...]
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f4eac1fa500) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4eac1ef000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55fb014bd000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4eac240000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f4eac1fb000, 113090)          = 0
getpid()                                = 4328
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, 4328)             = -1 EPERM (Die Operation ist     nicht erlaubt)
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55fb02077000
brk(0x55fb02098000)                     = 0x55fb02098000
write(1, "Hello World\n", 12Hello World
)           = 12
write(1, " 4328", 5 4328)                    = 5
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 ++
```

Did I something wrong or is it not possible that a process traces itself?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Did you start your program as root ? Ptrace requires elevated privileges to attach to other processes.

Comment: Sure I compiled and run it as root but the same error appears

Comment: Seems like quite a reasonable restriction.  What happens if you `fork()` a child process in which you `PTRACE_TRACEME` and exec `sleep`?  Can you attach to that from the parent?

Comment: The kernel won't  let a task attach to any task in its thread group, presumably to prevent deadlock.

Comment: @Ra'Jiska: It's trying to attach to itself.

Comment: @Benedict: your inline asm has a bug: you forgot to clobber `rcx` and `r11` (which are destroyed by `syscall` itself), and you should use `"=a"(ret)` as part of the same asm statement that makes the syscall.  It's not safe to assume that `rax` will stay unmodified between asm statements.  As far as the compiler is concerned, they're totally separate statements.

Comment: I am just a beginner at Linux Binaries. At the moment i am reading this book and i saw the code on page 90 (http://index-of.es/Miscellanous/Learning%20Linux%20Binary%20Analysis.pdf) and trying to do it myself. Maybe then you understand me better :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Process is not able to attach itself but a Parent can attach his child. Forking was the solution. Thank you for your answers. Now

```
strace -p $PID(of the child)
```

returns an error

If you are using

```
strace -f ./Programm
```

strace will attach to the child before the parent is able to do it and the syscall will fail.

Here I traced the parent

```
     [....]
     rk(0x562f67a93000)                     = 0x562f67a93000
     write(1, "My process ID : 1801\n", 21My process ID : 1801
     )  = 21
     clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f28dc5547d0) = 1802
     ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, 1802)             = 0
     --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_TRAPPED, si_pid=1802, si_uid=1000, si_status=SIGSTOP, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
     nanosleep({tv_sec=50, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ffc95baaf30) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons why this does not work.

One may be the behavior described in the manpage you have linked:

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html

Search for "Ptrace access mode checking" in this manpage.

The section following that words describes different security modules which can be configured in a way that regular users are not allowed to do ptrace on their own processes.

It can even be configured to disable "ptrace" completely (even if started by root).

Note that it will not be possible to access processes started by a different user (unless you are root).

Comment: I find `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0` is a convenient sysctl setting for a development desktop.  It allows tracing non-child processes, so you can attach to things with GDB instead of having to start them from within GDB.